# Android studio 2.2 change view id property from layout editor does not save change

Tags: android, android-studio

when I try to change the Id of view in android studio 2.2 if I change the value and leave the field some times it does not save the change sometime it does if I click enter button on my keyboard some time it empty the value sometimes it save it some times it save it with repeat of @id/@id/

this is happening with me with every thing in layout editor not just the ID field getting empty

https://i.imgsafe.org/7bc119de0c.png

https://i.imgsafe.org/7bc132eec3.png

```
            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center" android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" android:id="@+id/@+id/TxtRecipt"/>
```

so what is the problem with it or what is the best way to save the value.

I know this is basics of use and I am not suppose to ask such question but I tried every thing and nothing work I red the manual to find the correct way but no luck??

> after so many tries and searching I did not find the right answer it might be a >bug or something but I notes that when I use Tab It save correctly with no >problems